# clickonce app publish with MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, deployment, clickonce, biometrics

I have built a clickonce window form app meant to get biometrics of my clients. The database is MySql and the database is online. I want to deploy it so that they can install in their computers and capture their biometrics. How do i publish it so that all they submit will get into the online MySql?

Comment: You just need to have proper connection string in the application to the online mysql database. And the mysql should be connectable from the clients network.

Comment: Thanks Chetan! I have gotten the connection string. I am using 1and1.com as my host provider. Initially i used my localhost MySql to build but when i went online i changed the connection string. I also included the MySql.dll in when deploying. But when i run the clickonce i get the error: Unable to find any of the MySql host

Comment: Where is you mysql server hosted? Are you able to connect to is from your local machine ?

Comment: It is hosted on remote server online with a webhost company. No. only when i log on to my control panel in the web host platform.

Comment: Then you need to talk to the hosting provider about this. They should help you allowing access to the port